# Can't get loop to work after user input "y" in Rock, Paper, Scissors script

Tags: python

```
import random

print("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!\n")

player_wins = 0
computer_wins = 0
   
while(player_wins != 3 and computer_wins != 3):

    player = input("\nEnter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ").lower()
    while player not in ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']:
        player = input("\nEnter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ").lower()
    choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    computer = random.choice(choices)
    
    print(f"\nYou chose {player}, computer chose {computer}.")
    if player == computer:
        print(f"Both players selected {player}. It is a tie!")
    elif player == "rock":
        if computer == "scissors":
            print("Rock smashes scissors. You win!")
            player_wins += 1
        else:
            print("Paper covers rock. You lose.")
            computer_wins += 1
    elif player == "paper":
        if computer == "rock":
            print("Paper covers rock. You win!")
            player_wins += 1
        else:
            print("Scissors cuts paper. You lose.")
            computer_wins += 1
    elif player == "scissors":
        if computer == "paper":
            print("Scissors cuts paper. You win!")
            player_wins += 1
        else:
            print("Rock smashes scissors. You lose.")
            computer_wins += 1
            
    if player_wins < computer_wins:                      #prints out at the end who scored how much and who won.
        print ("\nYour score is", player_wins)
        print ("Computers score is",computer_wins)
        print ("\nComputer wins!.")

    if player_wins > computer_wins:
      print ("\nYour score is", player_wins)
      print ("Computers score is",computer_wins)
      print ("\nYou win!.")

    if player_wins == computer_wins:
      print ("\nYour score is", player_wins)
      print ("Computers score is",computer_wins)
      print ("\nIt's a tie!!.")

if (player_wins == computer_wins or player_wins > computer_wins or player_wins < computer_wins):
    repeat = input("\nPlay again? (y/n): ")
    if repeat.lower() != "y":
        print("\nThanks for playing!")
```

The "While loop" plays and prints end results, however after input "y" it won't run the loop again. "n" does produce the "Thanks for playing!" message though. I've only been working with Python for three days and brand new to coding in general. I've been working on making the game code more complex as I get comfortable, but I am now at a complete loss so any help or tips are appreciated!

Tried a seperate "while" and 'if" statement and adding "break" to the end chain, all give the same issue. After "y" input the game ends instead of looping.

Comment: It's because the question is outside the while loop and it does nothing after you answer y.

Comment: Okay, I've added it to the while loop, but now it asks after each round instead of at the end of best 2 of three and even with y input it prints "Thanks for playing!"

Comment: You need to think of a way to run the actual game and then do the asking within the same loop. For instance, running a while True and then checking if the score is 3 for either the player or computer, then you can ask if they want to play again and break the loop if not.

Comment: what if you make the user quit the program anytime? Would that not be a better implementation than only letting them quit after `player_wins == computer_wins or player_wins > computer_wins or player_wins < computer_wins` any of this condition is met?

Comment: Just put your loop inside a function "play_game" and run this function after you ask to play again.

Answer (score 0):

A better implementation of your game would be to allow users quit whenever they want to. I don't think a user should be made to keep playing until certain conditions are met. To implement this, I refactored your codes. I also simplified your multiple print statements using f-strings. This would be a better approach.

```
import random

print("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!\n")

choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
player_wins = 0
computer_wins = 0
   
while True:
    player = input("\nEnter a choice (rock, paper, scissors) or q to quit: ").lower()
    if player == 'q':
        print("\nThanks for playing!")
        break
    elif player not in choices:
        continue
    else:
        computer = random.choice(choices)
        print(f"\nYou chose {player}, computer chose {computer}.")
        if player == computer:
            print(f"Both players selected {player}. It is a tie!")
        elif player == "rock":
            if computer == "scissors":
                print("Rock smashes scissors. You win!")
                player_wins += 1
            else:
                print("Paper covers rock. You lose.")
                computer_wins += 1
        elif player == "paper":
            if computer == "rock":
                print("Paper covers rock. You win!")
                player_wins += 1
            else:
                print("Scissors cuts paper. You lose.")
                computer_wins += 1
        elif player == "scissors":
            if computer == "paper":
                print("Scissors cuts paper. You win!")
                player_wins += 1
            else:
                print("Rock smashes scissors. You lose.")
                computer_wins += 1
            
        if player_wins < computer_wins:                      
            print (f"\nYour score is {player_wins}\nComputers score is {computer_wins}\nComputer wins!.")

        if player_wins > computer_wins:
          print (f"\nYour score is {player_wins} Computers score is {computer_wins}\nYou win!.")

        if player_wins == computer_wins:
          print (f"\nYour score is {player_wins}\nComputers score is {computer_wins}\nIt's a tie!!.")
```